# Vue routing breaks if URL doesn't contain a hash (no input file specified)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, url-routing, vue-router

I need to run Vue router in its default mode (aka, hash mode, aka I can't run it in `history` mode). In that mode, all my dynamic routes contain a leading has, e.g. `http://myurl.com/#/highlights`. However, if you remove that leading hash, e.g. (`http://myurl.com/highlights`) the site breaks (gives the error `no input file specified`).

My goal is to ensure if none of the matched routing conditions are met, and the user is not authenticated, that the user is redirected to the login screen, and if they are authenticated but no routes are matched, they are redirected to the home page.

Here is my `router.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Programs from './views/Programs.vue'
import Sizzle from './views/Sizzle.vue'
import Login from './views/Login.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: {
        name: "login"
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: Login,
    },
    {
      path: '/highlights/:slug?',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      props: (route) => ({ slug: route.params.slug || categories[0].slug })
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: {
        name: "login"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

*Note that `categories` is a javascript variable I instantiate globally via script tag before any Vue.js files are loaded.

Comment: If you go with a routing strategy that removes the hash, you can not enter the site at any page but the `/` route. Meaning: If you try and go directly to /highlights/:slug - it won't work until you've first gone to `/`, vue has loaded, and programmatically moved you to that link.

Comment: Have you configured your server correctly to handle HTML5 history mode? Please read the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Comment: @Brant that's misleading.  You can enter that url in and vue-router will route you there. To the question, the default mode is to use a hash.  Therefore you have to have a hash in the url for the router to work.

Answer (score 0):

As the official documents say, the default mode for `vue-router` is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.

When you using history mode, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access `http://myurl.com/highlights` directly in their browser.

So, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same `index.html` page that your app lives in.

For more server configuration information, you can view this - [example-server-configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: I don't want to use history mode. I want to use hash mode - I just need to make sure if the URL doesn't start with a hash, or if there is no route match, that they still get redirected to the login screen, but right now that's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the `history.pushState` API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

to avoid the error when using history mode.
You need a proper server configuration,

### Example Server Configurations

#### Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### nignx

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

For more info. visit docs
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I don't want to use history mode or get rid of the hash  - I just need to make sure if the URL doesn't start with a hash, or if there is no route match, that they still get redirected to the login screen, but right now that's not happening.